# Change the table position to left 0 while its overflow in CSS

Tags: css

I thought each table row will move continuously move left to right but its overflowing :( I wanted when "T10" reach the end of the window it come on left :0 and start going to end, and when "T9" reach the end of window it come on left : 0 and start to end of window.... and so on....

```css
td {
  height :6vh;
  width:20vw;
  background-color: red;
  animation: flow 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes flow {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="T1"> </td>
  <td class="T2"></td>
  <td class="T3"></td>
  <td class="T4"></td>
  <td class="T5"></td>
  <td class="T6"></td>
  <td class="T7"></td>
  <td class="T8"></td>
  <td class="T9"></td>
  <td class="T10"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood exactly what you want. But I've added two variants of a ticker that do per-item animation. If you want to build more complex animations I'd recommend using something like https://greensock.com/gsap/. With JS you have so much more control over the timing - which is a pain when doing keyframes in CSS it is quite limited.

```css
.scroll-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -25%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: ticker;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-direction: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.scroll-item-alt {
  animation-name: ticker-alt;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-direction: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.T1 {
  animation-delay: 3000ms;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.T2 {
  animation-delay: 2000ms;
  background-color: orange;
}

.T3 {
  animation-delay: 1000ms;
  background-color: red;
}

.T4 {
  background-color: magenta;
}

.T1-alt {
  animation-delay: 2400ms;
}

.T2-alt {
  animation-delay: 1600ms;
}

.T3-alt {
  animation-delay: 800ms;
}

.T4-alt {
  animation-delay: 0ms;
}

@keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(400%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes ticker-alt {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(500%, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-wrapper">
  <span class="scroll-item T1">T1</span>
  <span class="scroll-item T2">T2</span>
  <span class="scroll-item T3">T3</span>
  <span class="scroll-item T4">T4</span>
</div>

<div class="scroll-wrapper">
  <span class="scroll-item scroll-item-alt T1 T1-alt">T1</span>
  <span class="scroll-item scroll-item-alt T2 T2-alt">T2</span>
  <span class="scroll-item scroll-item-alt T3 T3-alt">T3</span>
  <span class="scroll-item scroll-item-alt T4 T4-alt">T4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: i want when "T10" reach the end of the window it  come on left :0 and start going to end, and when "T9" reach the end of window it come on left : 0 and start to end of window.... and so on....

Comment: @Mr.kismat You mean like a news-ticker?

Comment: kind of , 
i am a beginner but i want to make what is inside my mind anyhow...

Comment: @Mr.kismat I've added two variants of a simple per-item keyframe animation. As I said in the edited answer, if you want more control over this, use JS.

Comment: thankyouuuuuuuuuuu soooooooooo muchhhhhhhhhh :) i will study this code now this is what i exactly wanted i had wasted 2 days but u solved it very easly thankyou soo much

Comment: @Mr.kismat You are welcome. The thing is that you have to animate the items individually because otherwise you cannot reposition them individually. If this has solved your problem please consider marking it as "accepted". :)